# $value in unidimensional integrals in R

Tags: r, integral

For my personal education, I was wondering what the **common role / usage** of **$value**, for example, in the code below for a unidementional integral in R is:

Again, my question what **$value** does and why when not included I sometimes get an error message?

```
integrate(function(x)dbeta(x, 10, 10)*dbinom(33,100,x),0,1)$value
```

Comment: `value` is the name of a member of the object returned by `integrate`

Comment: I checked the link you shared, Zheyuan, this is not a duplicate question. And I still need to know my answer. Thanks

Comment: Hubert's comment answers your question, no? If not, you can read the docs. Accessing lists in R is one of the first things a syntax guide would teach. Try here, for example: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Lists

Comment: Got it, many thanks.

Comment: sure Zheyuan, many thanks. It was truly helpful.